# Trouble Feeding Variables from a Form into a PHP Script Using the "$_POST" Command

Tags: php

I am having some difficulty feeding variables from my html form into my php. Would someone mind helping me, I have been at this for hours.

HTML CODE:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Welcome to Chorelistings - Log in Here</title>

 <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="test.php" class="login">
<h1>Chore Listings </h1>
<input type = "email" id="email"  name = "email" class = "login-input" placeholder = "Username (Email)">   
<input type="password" name="password "  id ="password" class="login-input" placeholder="Password">
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="login-submit">
 <p class="create-account"><a href="register.html">Create Account</a></p>

<p class="login-help"><a href="index.html">Forgot password?</a></p>
</form>




 </body>
 </html>
```

My VERY SIMPLE php script:

```
 <?php
    $email=$_POST['email']; 
     echo "hi";
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, try adding `method="post"` to the `<form>` tag:

```
<form action="test.php" class="login" method="post">
```

Secondly, inside your `test.php` file, try debugging what was actually sent:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
// or
var_dump($_POST);
// or for more info
print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

Thirdly, try to remove whitespaces when defining your input fields in html:

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="login-input" placeholder="Username (Email)">
```

And finally, add `<submit>` before closing `</form>` to your form to actually post the data.
Currently, I see you have links (`<a href>`) but that won't submit the form.

So your final html should look (simplified) like that:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<input type="text" name="email">
<submit>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no `method` on your form, so it's defaulting to GET, which doesn't send `$_POST` values.

Add `method="post"` to your `<form>` tag.

Comment: Next to <form action = "test.php"     ?

Comment: I think you mean to say `method`.

Comment: I do indeed mean `method`. My bad. I missed the [Ballmer Peak](https://xkcd.com/323/)

Comment: If I change the line to  <form action="test.php" action = "post" class="login"> it still says undefined index.

Answer (score 0):

A few things here. Your form does not specify a request method. Add a `method` attribute to your form tag like so:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php" class="login">
```

Next, just a side-note, there's no need for spaces when specifying your attributes, eg:

```
<input type = "email" id="email"  name = "email" class = "login-input" placeholder = "Username (Email)" />
```

You'll be good to go with:

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="login-input" placeholder="Username (Email)" />
```

A few (less common) things to think about -- make sure your `.htaccess` is not rewriting any post requests in an unwanted way. If you happen to have any file uploads within your form(s), make sure you specify the `enctype` attribute on your form eg:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Best of luck!